# How to parse JSON Response into Dictionary?

Tags: c#, wcf, json, json.net

I have a JSON resonse (HTTPWebResponse) coming back from my WCF Service. It looks like this :

```
{
    "New SessionResult": [
        {
            "Key": "Token",
            "Value": "token_value"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using JSON.NET (http://james.newtonking.com) and I cant figure out how to deserialize this response into a `Dictionary<string, string>.` I have tried several things but each one says in different wording "cannot convert JSON into sting". Currently I tried this :

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

If possible I could just get certain values to place directly into strings. 
Example) JSON response has key,value pair (Token,token_value), I want to get the value for the key "Token" and place it in the local string "string Token".

Anyone help please, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try the Newtonsoft.Json plugin: http://json.codeplex.com/

in your case you'd end up with something like:

```
 JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonResponseData);
 ...
 mydic.Add(json["New SessionResult"]["Key"], json["New SessionResult"]["Value"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Why change your code?

Just convert from "string, string" -> "string, dynamic" in your declaration.

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
```