# Deserialize Json map to List in c#

Tags: c#, json

I need to convert this type of json

```
{  
   "italy":[  
      {  
         "city":"rome",
         "people":100000
      },
      {  
         "city":"milan",
         "people":50000
      }
   ],
   "spain":[  
      {  
         "city":"barcelona",
         "people":100000
      },
      {  
         "city":"madrid",
         "people":2000
      }
   ]
}
```

into a list of this c# class

```
    class CityPeople
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public int People { get; set; }
    }
```

so, in this specific case i would like to have a List composed of 4 entries, 2 for italy and 2 for spain.

How can i deserialize the json into this class?

i tried to do a sandard deserialize like this but without success because the json is not a jsonarray

```
List<CityPeople> citiesPeople = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CityPeople>>(myJson);
```

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far.

Comment: updated the snippet

Comment: Your json is an object with two properties (`italy` and `spain`) and you're trying to deserialize it as a list of cities which is not possible.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14161675/993547

Comment: which can be a strategy to obtain the same result? do i have to manually parse the json string?

Comment: You could just parse it and then get the list of cities by calling the `DeserializeObject<List<CityPeople>>` on those json properties.

Comment: If you control the shape of the json, you can change it to an array of countries, with each country having a name property and an array of cities. That would map nicely to a list of country and city POCOs. Otherwise Patrick's comment - and Jon Skeet's answer he's linking to - seems like your best bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach is often the best one.

Why not add a class to your project that represents exactly what the json is:

```
public class CityInfo
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int People { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can Deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, CityInfo[]>` and build your `CityPeople` objects like so:

```
List<CityPeople> cityPeople = new List<CityPeople>();
foreach(var f in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, CityInfo[]>>(json))
{
    foreach(var i in f.Value)
    {
        cityPeople.Add(new CityPeople() {
            City = i.City,
            Country = f.Key,
            People = i.People
        });
    }
}
```

Working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/poZfbD)

Answer (score 1):

I solved doing a deserialize to a `Dictionary<string,CityPeople>` and then converting the dictionary to a list updating the city during conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonText);
        IEnumerable<CityPeople> cityPeople = obj.Cast<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>().SelectMany(kvp =>
        {
            return kvp.Value.ToObject<List<CityPeople>>().Select(c =>
            {
                c.Country = kvp.Key;
                return c;
            });
        });
```